# Typescript limit string to be a substring from api

Tags: typescript

OI have gotten two values from api, one is `fruit` and another is `vegetable`. I only know both type are string, but not the exactly values.

```
// fruit can be any string, not apple only, same on vegetable. I don't know what exactly value api return.
const fruit: string = 'apple'
const vegetable: string = 'onion'
```

I want to define a type `Food`, which can contain the substring `fruit` and `vegetable`.
As I don't know the return value from api, I cannot define a type like

```
type Fruit =  'apple' | 'banana'
const fruit: Fruit = 'apple
```

I know in this way, it's working. But my one is not `Fruit`, it's only `string`.

This is what I tried

```
type Fruit = typeof fruit
type Vegetable = typeof vegetable
type Food = `${Fruit} ${Vegetable} ${string}`
```

In this way, the type is `{string} {string} {string}`, the first two is not the exacly value from fruit and vegetable. The below is what I want

```
const test1: Food = 'a b c d'; // wrong
const test2: Food = 'apple onion c d'; // pass
```

How can I define that `Food` type if I cannot have a union type for the value, only can be a generic `string` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

The type system only works at compile time. That means that *before* your code ever runs. But a value from an external API wont exist until runtime. When you app is running there is no type system.

That means that if an API is typed to return `string`, that's the most you can know about it.

The closest thing you can do is a type predicate:

```
function hasApple(input: string): input is `${string}apple${string}` {
  return input.includes('apple')
}

const bad: `${string}apple${string}` = input // error

if (hasApple(input)) {
    const good: `${string}apple${string}` = input // works
}
```

But then you have to know *exactly* what you are looking for. So unless you know what strings could be returned, this won't help much.

The most specific a type of a runtime value can be is all the possibilities of that that runtime value.